# Broken hyperlinks in Acumatica help documentation

Tags: acumatica

I have noticed that many of the links in the Acumatica wiki help pages do not link to relevant content.

For example, this link is found in the wiki article on Executing Event Handlers and should be pointing to more information on PX.Data Delegates 
https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3ce58733-bf9c-d909-ae69-01db28ec45f6

The link above however redirects to here instead.
https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Help

I assume these links should be redirecting to reference pages. 
Does anyone know where is can find these reference pages?

Thanks in advance!
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Main` page appears to have been replaced by the `Help` page.

Instead of following links to `Main` page:

https://help.acumatica.com/**Main**?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3ce58733-bf9c-d909-ae69-01db28ec45f6

Try substituting `Main` with `Help` in the URL:

https://help.acumatica.com/**Help**?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3ce58733-bf9c-d909-ae69-01db28ec45f6

Comment: That works! much appreciated. I'll do this until Acumatica fixes the problem which I assume they will at one point.

Comment: I got confirmation that the documentation team is working on it.

Comment: Most excellent! I have been using the workaround in the meantime.